# Android Firebase Realtime Database - retrieve limited data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Chat app, and  i need to get 25 message only and when user scroll, he get the next 25 message, How can i do this using firebase?

Answer (score 0):

You use Firebase query here is the link for the Android docs:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query